# Issues when running Nativescript OCR plugin for iOS

Tags: ios, nativescript, ocr, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-plugin

First of all, sorry for my English. I'm running my Nativescript Angular App who uses the nativescript OCR 1.0.0 plugin. The recognition works good for Android OS but not for iOS. When I run the project in Visual Studio Code for MacOS, I have seen some issues like:

> /Users/macintosh/....../platforms/ios/Pods/TesseractOCRiOS/TesseractOCR/G8TesseractParameters.h:2353:5: warning: '@param' command used in a
>         comment that is not attached to a function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
>
> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/macintosh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/........-ewfwairpchlyrihgevrrenyiqein/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/visaselectronicas/BuildProductsPath/Debug-iphoneos/TesseractOCRiOS'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/macintosh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/...........-ewfwairpchlyrihgevrrenyiqein/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/......../BuildProductsPath/Debug-iphoneos/TesseractOCRiOS'
>   error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output
>   Ld /Users/macintosh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/...........-ewfwairpchlyrihgevrrenyiqein/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/............./IntermediateBuildFilesPath/.........../Debug-iphoneos/???.build/Objects-normal/armv7/....... normal armv7
>   note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description
>
> **Please call SetImage before attempting recognition**
>
> Recognize failed, check the log for possible details.

What can I do in order to use the OCR plugin for iOS and to recognize correctly an image?

Comment: Based on error log it sounds like you are not passing the right image source to retrieve text. Can you show us some code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I was not passing the right image source (Although it works on Android OS). I will post the answer with the code, before and after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original not working code part

```
doRecognize(args): void {
    let img: ImageSource = new ImageSource();
    img.fromAsset(args.imagenEnAsset);

    args.ocr.retrieveText({
        image: img,
        whitelist: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789<",     
        blacklist: "/Ñ,",
        onProgress: (percentage: number) => {
            console.log(`Decoding progress: ${percentage}%`);
        }
    })
```

Now working code part

```
doRecognize(args): void {
    let img: ImageSource = new ImageSource();
    img.fromAsset(args.imagenEnAsset)
        .then(
            (imageSource) => {
                if (imageSource) {
                    args.ocr.retrieveText({
                        image: imageSource,
                        whitelist: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789<",     
                        blacklist: "/Ñ,", 
                        onProgress: (percentage: number) => {
                            console.log(`Decoding progress: ${percentage}%`);
                        }
                    })
```